# C# MVC multipletabs session issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, session-state

We are facing one issue where a user is using multiple tabs, each tab will share one session for that particular user so we want each tab to have a unique session, we already have session mode in "InProc" so we added cookieless="UseUri" i.e. sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri".
Adding this helped us with each tab having a unique session however this worked only in IE private mode but not in IE normal mode, chrome & firefox, it gets stuck on login page, our login method is Azure Active Directory i.e. (Federation)authentication, the page keeps loading and its not moving to homepage of our application, I don't know what's going on could you please help.

FYI, we are storing class properties in session so using  sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri" is good or bad way?

Here is the code we have used for AAD authentication

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);  // Authentication type is cookies

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
               {
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
                            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

                      // Here the code all about certification & access token

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   }
               }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When a session is created, a cookie is sent down to the client with the session id, and something like a web browser will blindly send this cookie back for each request to the same domain, whether that be in one tab or a hundred. If the session cookie is received by the server, it will restore that session.

It works in "private" mode not because of the changes you made, but simply because in private mode each tab gets a totally unique context, including cookies. However, in a normal browsing mode, all tabs will have access to the cookie, and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: So what does this mean sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri" ?                                                                                                                            Could you help me to restrict the user when he opens a second tab in MVC ?

Comment: Anyone who can extend help ?

Comment: There's no help to be had. What you're wanting to do is not possible. Period. InProc simply means that the session storage will be in memory, tied to the running process (AppPool). That's really only useful in development, and should be changed to a more stable and reliable session storage provide in production. Cookieless means that the session id will be appended to the URL instead of set as a cookie. It's an extremely bad idea, because you're leaking the session. It is also deprecated. Neither has anything to do with what you're trying to achieve or help in that regard.

Comment: So Chris what approach should I take to store data and there is no issue even if its multipletabs open.